# HTML Custom attributes priority

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I haven't been able to to find, whether the standard for `data-` attributes should be considered as primary syntax or secondary.

Maybe with reference to some major framework, like Angular?

i.e. if someone specifies an attribute as both `my-attr` and `data-my-attr`, which one should be used first? I can't find it documented anywhere.

```
<div my-attr="123" data-my-attr="456"></div>
```

If we encounter something like this, what is the standard logic for processing it? Which value to use and which one to ignore in this case?

---

A little context. I wrote a library that used its own `my-attr` syntax, which later on I extended to support `data-my-attr` for compliance, but I added it as a secondary syntax, which is what I'm not sure about.

Comment: I don't think "Primary Syntax" means anything in terms of the DOM...? (if it does, can you post a reference?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Well, you have to make a decision on which attribute you are going to use when both are suddenly specified.

Comment: He is asking about the priority I think. Which one will be given higher priority if both are present.

Comment: @vitaly-t  it would be great of you can add some working demo example of your requirement.

Comment: @VicJordan I already have ;)

Comment: The first question would be whether custom non-`data` attributes are even allowed by the HTML5 spec. Without rendering the document invalid, that is.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Strictly speaking, they are not, but everybody is using them nonetheless. Developers often go for `data-` version only when their editor doesn't like custom attributes :) Which is the main reason I added it in my library.

Comment: @vitaly-t Well, if they're technically invalid, what specification would you expect to make statements about the priority of their processing? If it were my library, I'd give the valid HTML priority, but that's no more than an opinion. Another way of looking at it would be that `my-attr` could be considered the shorthand version of `data-my-attr`, in which case it would not be unreasonable to give priority to the longhand form.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yeah, I was hoping for something definitive, something written down somewhere. Otherwise, we can say that primary and secondary are whatever decided within the library that supports both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom attributes without the `data-` prefix should be considered **invalid**, because don't follow the standard and are not HTML validator compliant.

**Attributes with the `-data` prefix should have priority**, considering they are HTML compliant.

## Custom data attribute

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace **whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen**, is XML-compatible, and contains no characters in the range U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).

Source : https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

---

## Testing the provided example

If you go to https://validator.w3.org and test your example code ...

```
<div my-attr="123" data-my-attr="456"></div>
```

You will get this :

> Error: Attribute my-attr not allowed on element div at this point.

Comment: `Custom attributes without the data- prefix should be considered invalid.`. And what is the source of that information?

Comment: I attached a link, and quoted the paragraph where custom Attributes are described, if a custom attribute doesn't follow that specification, is invalid, and can cause errors in the  future

Comment: Yeah, I think this is starting to make sense... :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding from AngularJS point of view, **both will have equal priority**. and **Both can't be used together at same time**. You have to chose either `my-attr` or `data-my-attr`.

```
<div ng-model="model.first" data-ng-model="model.second">
```

Above will through compile time error of `Error: [$compile:multidir]`

**So you can not use them together**.

From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization) there is example which clearly tells this.

**Valid**:

```
Hello <input ng-model='name'>
Hello <input data-ng-model='name'>
```

**Invalid**: (Error: [$compile:multidir])

```
Hello <input ng-model='name' data-ng-model='name'>
```

[Plunker Demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xp67PWS2afIwPcib4NYj?p=preview).

Comment: Case in point, in Angular.js, which one will be used? - `<div ng-model="model.first" data-ng-model="model.second">`? I don't think both will work :)

Comment: And the standard for the `data-` one is: `var dataAtr = myDiv.dataset.myAttr`.

Comment: @vitaly-t please check my updated answer. As I mentioned at first also that both will have same priority i.e. one can be used at a time. I updated my answer from AngularJS point of view. Hope this will add some more clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the accepted answer was right to the point.